# texlua -e option in command line?

Tags: luatex

From what I read, you can pass lua code (instead of a script file) and run it in the command line like so: `lua -e "print('hello world')"`. With texlua, this does not work, and passing `--help` doesn't seem to explain this. am I missing something?

Comment: `texlua` requires a script file. Wouldn't it be easier to write it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you expected here. `lua` and `texlua` are completely different programs and they don't share *any* command line arguments. While `lua` has quite some interactive features, `texlua` is basically a shorthand for `luatex --luaonly` and therefore shares it's argument handling. This actually is "explained" by `--help`: No option to directly pass some Lua commands is mentioned, indicating that there is no such option.